# Catch invalid password on Sudo

Tags: try-catch, return-value, sudo, exit-code

Is there a way to trap/catch a invalid password when you use `sudo`? Basically I want to return a specific exit code if the `sudo` password is invalid. I don't want to avoid `sudo` or get around it, I just want to close/exit a script in a matter of my choosing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the man page of [sudo(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo), there is no easy way for evaluating the exact error reasons for a failure:

> ### Exit Value
>
> Upon successful execution of a program, the exit status from sudo will
>   simply be the exit status of the program that was executed.
>
> Otherwise, sudo exits with a value of 1 if there is a
>   configuration/permission problem or if sudo cannot execute the given
>   command. In the latter case the error string is printed to the
>   standard error. If sudo cannot stat(2) one or more entries in the
>   user's PATH, an error is printed on stderr. (If the directory does not
>   exist or if it is not really a directory, the entry is ignored and no
>   error is printed.) This should not happen under normal circumstances.
>   The most common reason for stat(2) to return ''permission denied'' is
>   if you are running an automounter and one of the directories in your
>   PATH is on a machine that is currently unreachable.

The only "ugly" approach, which comes to my mind is to parse the result of stderr to determine the error reason:

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile=`mktemp`

sudo echo "dummy" 2>$tmpfile

if [ $? == 1 ]; then
   if [ `cat $tmpfile | grep -x "sudo.*incorrect password attempts" | wc -l` == 1 ]; then
      # exit due to failed password attempts
      echo "too many failed password attempts"
   else
      # other reason, for instance configuration
      echo "other reason"
   fi
fi

rm $tmpfile
```

Note, however, that this approach is not upgrade-safe and moreover language-dependent: If a patch to sudo changes the text which is shown to the user in case of a wrong password, or the user logs on in a different language, this coding will not be able to handle this properly.